# Finding critical points of multivariate function

Tags: functions, multivariable-calculus

Use the product rule to find the first-order partial derivatives of the function

f(x, y) = (2x^2 + 2y^2 − 3)(4xy + 5).

Hence find the critical points of this function.

[Hint: You may find it helpful to consider the sum of the two first-order partial derivatives.]
how to solve?

fx= (2x^2 +2y^2-3)(4y)+(4xy+5)(4x)

fy= (4x)(2x^2+2y^2-3)+(4xy+5)(4y)

I dont know what happens when we add two partial derivatives, so I decided to go as usual. So, after equating fx to 0,I get

2x^2+2y^3-3y = -5-4xy

I am stuck after this!

Comment: What have you tried or where do you get stuk? Were you able to use the given hint?

Comment: I don't know how to use the hint though!

Comment: It helps if you add the owork you have done, e.g. what do you arrive at when you use the hint? The more context / personal effort you add to your question, the more likely you'll get help :-).

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

I'm assuming you can find both partial derivatives and the given hint suggests you add both equations, you should arrive at:
$$f_x+f_y = 0 \iff 8 x^3 + 8 y^3+ 24 x^2 y + 24 x y^2 + 8 x  + 8 y
 = 0$$
Now notice that you can simplify by dividing by 8 and factoring as follows:
$$\color{blue}{x^3 + y^3 + 3 x^2 y + 3 x y^2} + x  + y= \color{blue}{\left(x+y\right)^3}+\left(x+y\right)=\left(x+y\right)\left(\left(x+y\right)^2+1 \right)$$
You're looking for zeroes of this equation, does that help?

Comment: Can u explain why can we find the answer by adding partial derivatives?

Comment: is it simply that we equate both fx and fy to 0, so we can add them to 0 as well?

Comment: @KashmiraZambad Yes, it's simply a (possible) step in solving the system. If $f_x=0$ **and** $f_y=0$ have to hold, then $f_x+f_y=0$ has to hold as well. In this case, $f_x+f_y=0$ is easier to solve (or at least, get a part of the solution). Can you take it from there?

Comment: can it be like (x+y)^2= -1?

Comment: I think I am again confused in finding zeros of this equation, one will be x= -y

Comment: @Kashmira Zambad Squares (of real numbers) can never be negative but indeed, the other factor only turns 0 when $x=-y$. You can plug this into one of the initial equations and solve from there.